# Kernel of the evaluation map of a sheaf has global sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field, for example $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Consider a subspace $V$ of $\Gamma(X,F)$, the space of global sections of $F$. Now, $F$ may or may not be generated by the sections in $V$. But we still have an evaluation map:

$V\otimes\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow F$, which may not be surjective.

Let $K$ be the kernel of this morphism and $Q$ be the cokernel. So we have the exact sequence:

$0\rightarrow K\rightarrow V\otimes\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow F\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0.$

Is it true that $\Gamma(X,K)=0$? How do we see this? When will this happen?

Comment: If you take global sections (and your variety is connected) you get the exact sequence $0 \to \Gamma(X,K)\to V \to \Gamma(X,F)$ and the map $V\to \Gamma(X,F)$ is simply the inclusion, so that it is injective.

Comment: @DanieleA, That means that $(\Gamma(X,K)=0$ since it maps to 0 in $\Gamma(X,F)$ right?

Comment: Yes, the fact that the sequence is exact tells you that $\Gamma(X,K)$ is isomorphic to the kernel of $V\to \Gamma(X,F)$.